# write a text file from apache server red hat using php

Tags: php, linux

I've read some other answer that are quite similar, but my problem is that the text file is created but remain empty.
I don't get any error message. The same code works perfectly on windows server.
Permissions are ok: "apache" user CREATE the text file but ...

Can anybody help me?
Server apache 2.2
Red Hat 6
PHP 5

What else?
ok, the code

---

```
$oggi=date("Y").date("m").date("d").date("H").date("i").date("s");  
$file = "Business_Case_".$oggi.".xml";  
$f_handle = fopen($file, 'w');  
$sql = "select * from bc_inizio";  
$res = mysql_query($sql, $conn);  
while ($arrow = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {  
    $friga = hex2bin($arrow['riga'])."\n";  
    fwrite($f_handle, $friga);  
}  
fclose($f_handle);
```

---

"mysql_affected_rows" return, correctly, 1178 rows selected!!

Comment: What version of PHP 5 do you have?  If it is less than php 5.4, do you have hex2bin defined yourself?  (hex2bin wasn't added until 5.4)

Comment: What is the exact php error you are getting

Comment: php version: 5.3.3 ... but bin2hex works!  anyway, why no errors?

Comment: I had no error: I start the program and nothing happens.

Comment: bin2hex would work because it was introduced a long time ago, hex2bin however is recent.  The reason I ask is because if you call an undefined function and error reporting is off.  The fatal error would stop script execution thus preventing fwrite from ever being called, but not tell you anything is wrong.  To rule it out, we can add this before your while loop: `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Thank You! (I was out of office for some days) Now I checked it and everything's working. Thanks again for your help.